# How do I wire this motor so I can plug it into the wall?

Tags: soldering, wiring

A visual aid (2-minute video) for this question can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJRFl8ilQRI&feature=youtu.be).

Hello!  Currently this motor is powered by two batteries sourced by genteq.  I would like to rewire it such that it can be plugged into a standard wall socket (San Francisco, CA, USA).  I don't want to hurt myself, power down the entire apartment building, etc. (insert other stupid thing I want to avoid).

#### I have:

```
1.  Wire strippers
2.  Voltmeter
3.  A male wall socket that I can cut out of an old appliance
```

#### Unfortunately, I don't have:

```
1.  Solder
2.  Soldering iron
3.  Crimper
4.  Extra lengths of wire (I know where to acquire this in a jiffy)
```

Comment: Sorry, but few of us will watch a video for you. Post a photo and link to the spec sheet for the motor. If the motor has a rating plate then post a photo of that. If the motor is DC as suggested by your mention of batteries then you can't run it directly from mains. I suspect that "gentec" is a brand name and should be capitalised. If the brand is relevant then post a link to the website datasheet for the batteries.

Comment: That's not a battery, it's a motor capacitor, which means that this is an AC motor of some sort, but as previously mentioned your question is unanswerable without the motor data sheet or at least data plate.  Even pictures of the wiring would be preferable to video.  More pragmatically as a younger experimenter you should probably not be trying to do mains powered projects - there are safety hazards as you've realized, and it takes more experience to understand them.  What is your goal and why do you think this motor is suitable to aid in achieving it?

Comment: Those "batteries" are really capacitors - many AC motors require capacitors for starting or running.  Are there any other wires or connection points on the motor?  Any label or nameplate on the motor itself?  What was the motor originally used for?

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's start with the biggest problem - that's not a battery you're holding - it's a capacitor. That's actually a good thing, (maybe) since it means you don't have a DC motor. In principle, you might even get it to work from the wall. On the other hand, with a motor that size, the fact that the cap is rated "440 VAC" say you may be out of luck. VAC means "volts AC", and you won't get 440 out of your wall socket. It might be possible to find a surplus transformer which will do the job, but it will be big and heavy (about the same as the motor, or worse) and it will *not* be cheap. However, not all is hopeless, since the cap rating may not be the same as the motor - but that's the way to bet.

First, though, you need to examine the motor carefully and find its nameplate. This will give you the motor model number, voltage and power (among other things). With the motor model in hand, it's time for Google.

Take what you learn, and if that's not enough make another question, incorporating *everything* you've found.

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's patience.  A similarly beginner-level question on StackOverflow would probably have been downvoted 5 times and removed by now.  I should probably write another question, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to rotate my body at a constant speed so I can take a video of that rotating body.  I have a Lazy Susan that can hold my weight, so I'm looking for the cheapest and easiest way to make me rotate at a constant speed.  I thought of getting a fan and making some sort of windmill, but figured hooking a motor up directly would be easier and more reliable

Comment: @frank - Once again, find the nameplate. It will list (among other things) the nominal rpm of the motor under full voltage. If the motor is synchronous, it will be locked to the line frequency, and you're almost certainly out of luck. Otherwise, you may be able to run the motor at lower voltage and get lower speed - but then again, perhaps not, or at least not reliably. But above all else, FIND THE DAMN NAMEPLATE.